# Discriminant of Finite-Dimensional Extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: galois-theory, determinant, p-adic-number-theory

For an $n$-dimensional extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, we have $K$'s "ring of integers" $\mathcal O_K$ and its uniformizer $\varpi$.  We also have the ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$, with $\mathcal O_K$ the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $K$.  I believe that from a basis $v_1, ... , v_n$ of $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$, we can multiply each element by a sufficiently high power of $\varpi$ so that the resulting collection $w_1, ... , w_n$ is an integral basis of $\mathcal O_K$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.\

With this in mind, I believe we can extend the notion of a discriminant of an algebraic number field to an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, by defining $Disc(K)$ to be the square of the determinant of the matrix whose $i,j$th entry is $\sigma_i(w_j)$, where $\sigma_1, ... , \sigma_n$ are all the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-embeddings of $K$ into an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  I

Is this definition appropriate?  When is it the same as the polynomial discriminant, and why?  For example, when $K$ is an Eisenstein extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, with $\varpi$ the root of an Eisenstein polynomial $f$ with other roots $\varpi', \varpi''$ etc., why is it true that $Det( (\sigma_i(w_j) )^2 = (\varpi - \varpi')^2(\varpi - \varpi'')^2(\varpi' - \varpi'')^2 \cdots$?

Comment: Not every $\mathbb Q_p$-basis can be adjusted simply by powers of the local uniformizer to give a $\mathbb Z_p$ basis for the (local) integers. Further, it is not always the case that the local integers are of the form $\mathbb Z_p[\alpha]$, so the discriminant of the ring of integers needn't match the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of any $\alpha$, etc.

Comment: okay, but in case of an Eisenstein (totally ramified) extension, apparently they do match up (as claimed by a paper by Chad Awtrey I'm trying to read through).  Furthermore, he claims that $ord_p(disc(f)/e) = ord_p(f'(\varpi))$, where $e$ is the ramification index of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\varpi$ is a uniformizer and a root of the Eisenstein polynomial $f$.  do you know why this is so?

Comment: If the extension is totally and _tamely_ ramified, then this would indeed be standard: as in Lang's "Alg No Th" pages 52-53, and then elementary things from the next chapter on discriminants and differents. In particular, the discussion mostly reduces to equations $X^e-\varpi=0$.

Comment: I'll have a look.  thank you for your help.

Comment: @paulgarrett my comment is coming quite a few years late, but it *is* always the case that the local integers have the form $\mathbf Z_p[\alpha]$.  It's the global case when the ring of integers sometimes doesn't have a power basis. See Lang "Alg No Thy" p. 59.

Comment: @KCd, aha! I didn't know that the local case worked out better! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the usual definition of the discriminant ideal of any finite (separable) extension of Dedekind domains $A\to B$. When $A$ is principal, the discriminant ideal is generated by the discriminant as you defined.

Note that $\mathcal O_K$ is always monogeneous (generated by one element) over $\mathbb Z_p$. More generally, finite separable extensions of complete DVR with separable residue extension are monogeneous, see *e.g.* Serre, Local fields, III.6.